# Stress test and Load test using Nightwatch.js or other tool

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, nightwatch.js

I have a quiz tool and I want to see how can I test this for 100 simultaneous users. This quiz tool have JS for its front-end and the JS is calling RESTful API.

I have some tests running on for trivial stuffs like login in Nightwatch.js for my web application but the question is how it can guarantee a number of simultaneous users?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware none of the load testing tools will execute JavaScript, so the options are in:

- If you need to simulate load directly on front-end and check rendering speed as well as REST backend performance you should go for browser-based testing using i..e [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2)
- If you think that simulating the load on REST backend will be enough you can simulate the load using i.e. [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html) or [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter).

Personally I would combine above approaches i.e. created the main load with SoapUI or Apache JMeter and checked JS frontend client-side performance either manually using something like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or in automated manner using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) depending on if there is an adhoc activity or something which will be executed on the regular basis.